# How to accept Http and Https adequately based on context request

Tags: php, symfony, https, silex

When using Silex, I define a simple route like this:

```
 $app->get('/hello', function() use ($app, $help){             
    $response = new Response( 
       json_encode( array("message"=>"hello") ), 400 
    );
    return $response; 
 });
```

- With: `curl -X GET -i -c cookies.txt http://mysite/web/hello`.
- I get: `{"message":"hello"}`

But

- With: `curl -X GET -k -i -c cookies.txt https://mysite/web/hello`
- I get: `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

*How can I define the same route for both, http and https, based on the security context in the request ?*

**UPDATE1: EXTRA INFORMATION**

Apache2 is configured in the following way:

***default***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName   mysite

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydev
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/mydev/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

***default-ssl***

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerName   mysite

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydev
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/mydev/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ... Using default Apache2 configuration
        SSLEngine on


        #   A self-signed certificate can be ...
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/user1/ssl/server.key.insecure
...
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is your webserver configured to use the same documentroot for mysite:80 and mysite:443?

Comment: Yes, As showned in the the two files added, it seems ok, to my knowledge.

Comment: Seems ok. I still suspect a configuration issue, as the same thing is working for me perfectly. If you just put a simple index.html there, can you access that?

Comment: I don't see `SSLCertificateFile` setting in your Apache ssl config. Did you missed to paste it here, or does not exist at all in config ? And `mod_ssl` is loaded ? Also you could check [this](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts) link, from apache wiki.

Comment: Are you sure the 404 is coming from silex. It looks like it is coming from apache, making this not silex specific at all.